# Celery run task periodically only next 5 days

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a celery task and i need it to run only next five days at 12.30am. How do i do this using celery-beat. I know how to run it periodically forever but not able to figure out for only next five days Any idea?

Comment: have you had luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the celery-beat docs for [crontab](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules).  Though if this is literally a one time thing, then by definition, it isn't exactly periodic.  You could set up a crontab periodic task to run at 12:30am for the next 5 days, but you would have to also remember to manually turn that off.

If you go this route

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-at-midnightish': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=30,),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `eta` keyword on `apply_async` as mentioned in the [celery faq](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#module-celery.task.base)

Comment: Agreed, but i need not turn off it manually. Is there any way of automatically turn off it after five days.